# If $A,B,C$ commute, then they are mutually diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm familiar with the fact if two matrices commute then they are mutually diagonalizable. For three matrices however, I'm unsure how conclude it.

If one of the matrices, say $A$, is non degenerate (all its eigenspaces are of dimension 1) this is trivial. But in the case of $m$ degenerate eigenspaces spanned by $\{x_1^j,\ldots,x_{n_j}^j\}_{j=1}^m$ we need to diagonalize $B,C$ simultaneously with linear combinations of eigenvectors from the same eigenspace only. I'm not sure how to continue with that.

Comment: This result is a generalization of spectral theorem. You can find a nice proof either in the chapter on finite Fourier analysis in Stein's Fourier analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result can be generalized : if $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ is a family (finite or not, countable or not...) of diagonalizable matrices such that $A_iA_j=A_jA_i$ for all couples $(i,j)\in I^2$, then exists a regular matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}A_iP$ is diagonal for all $i\in I$.

Work with associated endomorphisms $(a_i)$ of $\mathbb R^n$, by induction on the dimension $n$ : the case $n=1$ is trivial. Suppose it is true for all dimensions lower or equal than $n$. Consider a family of permutable diagonalizable endomorphisms $(a_i)$ of $\mathbb R^{n+1}$.

If all $a_i$ are scalar, then it's over. If not, take one, say $a_{i_0}$, that has at least two eigenspaces. Work on each eigenspace to build a basis composed of eigenvectors of all other endomorphisms. This basis also diagonalize  $a_{i_0}$. Over.